# JavaMail save Password

Tags: java, security, passwords, jakarta-mail

I am working on an implementation of javamail in my current program. The testmails are sent successfully if I  predefine the credentials directly in the code or if I write it via text/password Fields, but I want it more userfriendly. I'm using a MySQL DB for my program where I could store the smtp password but for security reasons I don't want it in cleartext and the only option I know would be a synchronous encryption and use the users login password as the security password.

Are there any other options to store the password safely or even a other option that the user doesn't need to enter his password all the time?
For sure, this will only be an option via checkbox for saving credentials, if the user doesn't want this he has to write it all the time.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score -1):

Store the password encrypted (hashed) in the database. Encrypt with the libs of [Apache Common](http://commons.apache.org/) for example:

```
String password = "PASSWORD_TO_ENCRYPTED";
String salted = password + username; //salt the password value, using the username is only an example 
String hash = DigestUtils.sha256Hex(salted.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

If you want to check if a given password is correct, salt it and hash it same way.. and compare the hash strings with the value stored in the database.

Comment: That won't help you save a password that you need to retrieve in order to send it to the mail server to login.